# Pattern.compile.split vs StringBuilder iteration and substring

Tags: java, string, optimization, split

I have to split a very large string in the fastest way possible and from what research i did i narrow it down to 2 possibilities:

1.`Pattern.compile("[delimiter]").split("[large_string]");`
2. Iterate through `StringBuilder` and call `substring`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[large_string]");
ArrayList<String> pieces = new ArrayList<String>();
int pos = 0;
int currentPos;
while((currentPos = sb.indexOf("[delimiter]", pos)) != -1){
    pieces.add(sb.substring(pos, currentPos));
    pos = currentPos+"[delimiter]".length();
}
```

Any help is appreciated , i will benchmark them but i'm more interested in the theoretic part : why is one faster then the other .

Furthermore if you have other suggestions please post them.

**UPDATE:** So as I said I've done the benchmark , generated 5 mil strings each having 32 chars , these were put in a single string delimited by `~~` :

1. `StringBuilder` approach , surprisingly ,  was the slowest with an avg of `2.50-2.55 sec`
2. `Pattern.compile.split` come on 2nd place with an avg of `2.47-2.49 sec`
3. `Splitter` by Guava was the undisputed winner with an avg of `1.12-1.18 sec` **half the time** of others (special thanks to ***fge*** who suggested it)

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Are you splitting on a regular expression or just a literal string?

Comment: I would use the split method, just because I like less code. I am not sure whether the StringBuilder method will be any faster in application. Maybe run your two options on large input strings and compare their performance.

Comment: @arshajii regular expression but i didn't put it in the question to not over complicate it

Comment: It makes a difference :)

Comment: `pos = currentPos+"[delimiter]".length();` <-- I don't believe this is what you intend

Comment: You should just test both versions with real world input. And a suggestion: If you do any benchmarking of the two versions and are still using Java 6, please take the time to also run the tests on Java 7 since the implementation of `String.substring` changed significantly in the new version, and the outcome might be different in both versions.

Comment: @arshajii i see ... then i have the option just to use literal string

Comment: @fge to not get the same position twice but `currentPos+1` would suffice

Comment: @Axel Note though that he's using `StringBuilder.substring()` not `String.substring()`

Comment: This is not what I'm talking about: `pos` is an int, but the expression returns a string :p

Comment: Looking at the source code for the regex split method, it looks like both methods are rather similar. It boils down to the relative speed of Matcher.find() versus StringBuilder.indexOf() methods.  (That is excluding the time and memory it would take to to create a separate string builder with a copy of your huge string).

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but for benchmarking I'd suggest you have a look at [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) -- unless you already use it

Comment: @Bohemian Yes. I just checked implementaions in Java 6 and 7, and both use copy in `StringBuilder.substring`.

Comment: @Axel i'm using java 6 but its good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a fixed pattern, and you do not need a regex, you might want to consider [Guava's `Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html). It is very well written and performs admirably:

```
private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on("myDelimiterHere");
```

Also, unlike `.split()`, you don't get nasty surprises with empty strings at the end... (you must pass a negative integer as an argument in order for it to do a "real" split)

You will also see that this class' `.split()` method returns an `Iterable<CharSequence>`; when the string is REALLY large, it only makes the necessary copies you ask it to make!

Comment: @fge empty strings at the end can be dealt with using standard split with the right (surprise) parameters.

Comment: +1 thx for the alternative, i will include it in my benchmark as well

Comment: @Bohemian I know... But the default behaviour is freakin annoying

Comment: Annoying, yes, but worse, surprising. it doesn't follow the design guideline of "least astonishment". Many, many questions on SO exist because of this.

Comment: @fge its useful to know this copy only on demand feature of `split` method

Comment: @Stephan it is especially useful since if you have to do pattern matching inside a subsequence, `Matcher`'s methods take a `CharSequence` as an argument

Comment: @fge please check my update . thanks again for the help man ur solution was by far the best :D

Comment: @Stephan Guava is a gold mine in general ;)

Answer (score 3):

If your string is large, something to consider is whether any copies are made. If you don't use StringBuilder but use the plain `String#substring(from,to)`, then *no* copies will be made of the contents of the string. There will be 1 instance of the *whole* String, and it will stick around as long as at least 1 substring persists.

Hmm... Source perusal of the Pattern class shows that split does the same thing, while the source of the StringBuilder shows that copies are made for each substring.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use it multiple times, a static object of your Pattern would be the choice. Look into the StringBuilder. The method indexOf is doing the same, iterating through all characters. Internally the String.split() method is also using Pattern to compile and split the string. Use the given methods and you should have the best performance...